# FileStream, сохранение на диск

Tags: c#, .net

Хочу реализовать скачивание файла по сети с возможностью приостановки скачивания. Делаю с помощью такого кода:

```
        using (var fw = new FileStream(Destination, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            fw.Seek(LoadedSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            int bytesRead = -1;
            var buffer = new byte[size];

            while (State == InProcess)
            {
                getdata(buffer,bytesRead);
                fw.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                fw.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

Проблема в том, что данные пишутся видимо в какой-то буфер или оперативную память, и на диск записываются только после завершения записи. Т.е после запуска размер файла 0, и остается пустым до остановки.
Можно ли сделать так, что бы данные писались на диск каждую секунду? Плохой ли это подход? Что будет если программа внезапно упадет, а данные не запишутся.
Может кто-то знает как сохранение реализовано в популярных менеджерах загрузок (в dm например, при старте загрузки создается файл уже необходимого размера, т.е. место резервируется заранее, а потом как-то пишет в этот файл)?

Comment: Готовый пример по одной из первых ссылок гугла: http://www.csharpcoderr.com/2012/08/download-a-file.html

Comment: > getdata(buffer,bytesRead); 

а вы уверены, что bytesRead бывает равна чему-то, кроме -1? И что в buffer что-то записывается?

Answer (score 2):

Вы не выложили всего кода, не понятен ваш алгоритм, похоже, в вашем коде есть ошибка.

Запись содержимого буфера в файл: `fw.`[`Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2bw4h516.aspx)`()`.
Делать это каждую секунду, крайне не рекомендую, создаст повышенную нагрузку.
Если программа упадет, содержимое буфера останется не записанным в файл.
Не забывайте также делать `fw.`[`Dispose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms227422.aspx)`()`.

**UPD**
В вашем случаи, `Dispose` гарантированно вызовется при выходе из блока `using`, также, 
при возникновении исключения, буфер запишется в файл.

Comment: @ildar: `using` вызывает `Dispose` автоматически в конце блока.

Comment: @ildar Утверждение про то, что если в программе будет исключение, то содержимое буфера не будет записано в файл, неверно. Для `FileStream` есть строгая гарантия, что [`Close` и `Dispose` вызывают `Flush`,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911408/does-stream-dispose-always-call-stream-close-and-stream-flush) соответственно, наличие блока `using` гарантирует, что `Flush` вызовется, если произойдет исключение.

Comment: @VladD, да вызывает, это я для общего развития написал. Прошу прощения за неполноту ответа, упустил из виду блок `using` в коде автора.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, да, если внутри блока using происходит исключение, вызовется `dispose`, который запишет буфер в файл. 
Аналогично, прошу прощения за неполноту ответа.

Comment: Flush() и так вызывается каждую секунду, но запись в файл не происходит. Записывает только после выхода из using. Объясните пожалуйста, что значит повысит нагрузку?

Comment: @gcoder: а вы уверены, что код внутри `while` выполняется? Или что `bytesRead` не всегда имеет значение `-1`?

Comment: конечно уверен, в конце концов файл копируется. Просто его размер меняется мгновенно с 0 до скаченного. Видно я плохо сформулировал вопрос.

Comment: что значит повысит нагрузку? - нагрузка на диск, это довольно затратная операция, если часто записывать небольшой объем данных, и вообще это не очень оптимально, лучше сначала подкопить данные, потом записать, думаю, FileStream сам за этим следит, если вручную Flush не вызывать.